# In OLS, can I use the ratio of two regressor as an additional regressor?

Tags: least-squares

Suppose I am regressing Y on x and z. Would there be any concern if I also include x/z as an additional regressor? i.e. I am regressing y on x,z and x/z
Thanks!

Comment: How strongly correlated are x, z, & x/z? My guess is you'll have a [tag:multicollinearity] issue.

Comment: This is essentially adding an interaction term to your model, if you are already familiar with those (i.e. similar to regressing x, z, and x*z)

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing but an interaction. You might have seen y= f(x,z,x*z)

instead of using x*z, you are using x/z. if there is no multi-colinearity(as Gung stated), you should not have any problems